# How can ndisasm use packsswb in 16-bit mode?

Tags: nasm, x86-16

Consider the file generated by the following Bash shell code:

```
echo -n "\x0f\x63\x42\xac" > binarydata
```

Now I run ndisasm on the file to see which instructions it would represent:

```
ndisasm -b 16 binarydata
```

and I get

```
00000000  0F6342AC          packsswb mm0,[bp+si-0x54]
```

According to [an x86 reference](http://books.google.de/books?id=uxkz5ZBwOWEC&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162), it is not available on Pentium, which implements the x86-32 superset of the 16-bit instruction set. So how can ndisasm use it in 16-bit mode?

Comment: 16-bit mode isn't "Pentium mode", most instruction set extensions work there too.

Comment: @harold: How do I prevent it from using the extensions and just output `db` like it usually does when it can't recognize?

Comment: I don't know, there doesn't appear to be a command line option with that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MMX-istructions can be used within the 16 bit mode and within the realmode too (using a Pentium MMX).

And the only one difference between the 16 bit mode and the 32 bit mode (using an intel 80386+) is the meaning and the usage of the address-size- and operand-size- prefixes inside of our code segment.

Dirk

Comment: That's not quite the *only* difference.  VEX prefixes (for AVX and some BMI instructions) aren't supported in real mode.  (But are supported in 16-bit *protected* mode, as well as other 32 and 64-bit modes.)  Apparently some existing real-mode code used invalid encodings of `les` (C4) / `lds` (C5) as intentional traps, so interpreting them as VEX would break such code.